# login variable disappeared from AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider class

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am looking at this Amazon official documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-amazon-cognito-with-swift-sample-app-developer-guide-and-more/

In this example code there is a variable callaed **logins** as part of **AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider**. Unfortunately, when I try to implement this in my app the logins variable does not exist anymore. I checked the class definition and it is not there. Anyone has an idea on how to get this back?

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
credentialsProvider.logins = [AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue: token]
```

Answer (score 0):

That API was removed as part of the 2.5.0 release. [Changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#250)

The new API from AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider is:

```
- (void)setIdentityProviderManagerOnce:(id<AWSIdentityProviderManager>)identityProviderManager;
```

AWSIdentityProviderManager:

```
@protocol AWSIdentityProviderManager <NSObject>

/**
 Each entry in logins represents a single login with an identity provider. The key is the domain of the login provider (e.g. 'graph.facebook.com') and the value is the OAuth/OpenId Connect token that results from an authentication with that login provider.
 */
- (AWSTask<NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *> *)logins;

@optional
/**
 * If the token contains the role arn and there are multiple roles, return the custom role to assume.  This is currently only supported for SAML identity providers.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *customRoleArn;

@end
```